# How to set text alignment in dynamically created FixedDocument

Tags: c#, documentviewer, fixeddocument

I am creating a report through FixedDocument and I am doing it in the code behind to dynamically add data to the report.

I started using FixedDocument today and got stuck in aligning texts. It does not seem to center align. Here's my code:

```
using System.Windows.Documents;
....
public void GenerateReport()
{
    FixedDocument document = new FixedDocument();
    PageContent content = new PageContent();

    FixedPage page = new FixedPage();
    page.Width = document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Width;
    page.Height = document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Height;
    page.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.AliceBlue;

    //header first line
    System.Windows.Controls.Canvas canvas = new System.Windows.Controls.Canvas();
    canvas.Width = document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Width;

    FixedPage.SetTop(canvas, 15);
    FixedPage.SetLeft(canvas, 15);

    System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock block = new System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock();
    block.FontSize = 11;
    block.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
    block.FontFamily = new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily("Tahoma");
    block.Text = "This is the first line";
    block.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
               
    canvas.Children.Add(block);

    page.Children.Add(canvas);

    //header second line
    System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock block2 = new System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock(); block.FontSize = 11;
    block2.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
    block2.FontFamily = new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily("Tahoma");
    block2.Text = "Daily Report";

    var canvas2 = new System.Windows.Controls.Canvas();
    canvas2.Children.Add(block2);

    FixedPage.SetTop(canvas2, 30);
    FixedPage.SetTop(canvas2, 30);
    FixedPage.SetLeft(canvas2, 15);
    FixedPage.SetRight(canvas2, 15);

    canvas2.Width = document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Width;
                
    page.Children.Add(canvas2);

    ((IAddChild)content).AddChild(page);
    document.Pages.Add(content);
}
```

How will I do the alignment right?

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.flowdocument?view=net-5.0#properties
I'm not sure if you can do this with FixedDocument. This is available in Flowdocument though with the TextAlignmentProperty.

Comment: Can you update your answer to include the relevant details from the linked post? This helps preserve your answer in the event the linked page disappears or is moved in the future.